# What is a polite way to call something a conspiracy theory?

Tags: politeness

"Conspiracy" has <s>acquired</s> a negative connotation.
[Edit: As pointed out in the comments, it has always had a negative connotation.]

If you tell or even insinuate to someone that what they are saying is a conspiracy theory you can be assured that the conversation will soon be coming to an end and the person might begin to dislike you.

Perhaps there is a conspiracy in this, but the word itself has become tainted with terrible imagery. When you hear "conspiracy" you start thinking of a bearded crackpot wearing a tinfoil hat living in a cabin the woods with no internet connection and a shotgun by the bed.

If you tell someone that you think what they are saying is a conspiracy theory they will start to think you are seeing them as the bearded crackpot. They might think you do not respect them (who respects that type of character?) which can lead to resentment and eventually dislike. This is fine if you are talking to someone you don't like, don't know or have no intention of becoming friends with. But when you are talking to friends and / or family members this is not the desired outcome. Even when you don't think this about your friend of family member they can still become offended.

**So the question is**, how can you tell someone that you think what they are saying is a conspiracy theory without offending them?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think "conspiracy" has ever had a positive connotation. That said, when I hear "conspiracy theory", I start thinking of Julia Roberts.

Comment: Just say their theory is *interesting, but a little far-fetched*. If they ask what you mean by *far-fetched*, tell them you think it's unlikely all the parties involved would all be acting in accord with some secret agreement intended to further their own interests (I assume that's what you mean by a *conspiracy theory*). btw - I'm not sure you can really say *conspiracy* has "acquired" negative connotations. When did it ever *not* have them?

Comment: I think you should reword your bottom-line question. I think it's possible to tell someone, "That sounds like a conspiracy theory" without "offending" them; moreover, you can use less controversial terms, but still speak your mind in an offending way. Call it whatever you want – your tone and body language can be way more offensive than the words "conspiracy theory," even if a conspiracy does have negative connotations.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'conspiracy theory' here? I think that might help.

Comment: I am surprised that none of the answers has yet tackled the issue of *why* the term is viewed so negatively. Read this article: http://www.globalresearch.ca/weaponizing-the-term-conspiracy-theory-disinformation-agents-and-the-cia/5524552

Comment: Use a synonym -- https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/conspiracy

Comment: The term conspiracy theory **per** se is not related to politeness/impoliteness. Perhaps you mean a euphemism for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might ask them,  “Have you checked your facts?”

With some people, expressing any doubt at all is going to offend them.  But expressing an alternative theory, without commenting on the proffered conspiracy theory, might work.  Just quote [Hanlon's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor),  “Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity”, or Heinlein's variant,  “You have attributed conditions to villainy that simply result from stupidity”, or a possibly-Bonaparte variant,  “Never ascribe to malice that which is adequately explained by incompetence”.

Also:

> Many journalists have fallen for the conspiracy theory of government. I do assure you that they would produce more accurate work if they adhered to the cock-up theory.
>   —Sir Bernard Ingham

Comment: +1 for hanlon's razor. if i only teach my kids 2 things in life, this is one of them. the other is that life is not a zero sum game.

Answer (score 2):

There is no polite way to say it, because it's not polite.

"Conspiracy Theory" is just a way to shrug off an idea you find threatening, it doesn't really matter the words used.

The idea the the moon landings were staged is bunkum, because the facts clearly contradict it. Not because someone else has labelled it a conspiracy theory.

Comment: A "conspiracy theory" is a particular sort of (usually wrong) theory that relies on an attractive pattern of explanation that is inherently at once highly implausible and highly compelling to the human mind. Namely, it relies on the idea of secret conspiracies. Faked moon landing ideas are wrong because they're contradicted by fact, yes, but it is useful to indicate why they are dubious to begin with, and also why they are so popular: labeling them "conspiracy theories" aids in both.

Answer (score 1):

since "conspiracy theory" has a bad connotation, simply don't use that phrase.  fundamentally a conspiracy theory is just an explanation of observed phenomenon that relies on several people working together in secrecy (aka conspiring).  simply explain how their theory relies on that assumption, without using the word conspiracy.

examples

> so you are saying bob, joe and jane got together and agreed to never call you?  and they kept the agreement secret from you for years?

or

> are you suggesting there is a large group of people opposed to the construction of the new mall, but none of them are willing to admit it publicly at the town hall meetings?

some people (mis)use "conspiracy theory", when they really mean "outlandish theory". in that case, perhaps you could simply explain what about the theory you find "outlandish".

example:

> i find it highly unlikely that your father drove across five states just to buy an in-and-out burger.  i realize he's a big fan of animal style, but perhaps you just don't want to accept the fact that he is dating your professor.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting-point would be to look at how the people who believe the theory describe it in their own words.  Unless your friend uses very bizarre terms, you can often use the same vocabulary they do.  There’s a risk of miscommunication, if true believers read different implications into those words, but you aren’t going to insult them. (As long as you can keep a straight face.)

In general, words like “plot,” “secret history,” “cover-up” and “hidden” don’t have the same negative connotations as “conspiracy theory.”  Although note that people often say they believe in a “conspiracy,” just not a “conspiracy theory.”

Comment: @StuartF I think, if my reply to that started, “Your conspiracy theory, ...,”  most people would be offended. The implication of “I know this sounds like a conspiracy theory, but, ...,” is that it’s really not one. If I were trying to reassure them, I might say something like “so-called conspiracy theory” or “quote-unquote conspiracy theory.”

Answer (score -1):

Much of what is called 'conspiracy theory' is really just a radically-different account to the conventionally-accepted version of things.

Many of these have been vindicated as true in the past, and if a person wants to be as objective as possible in their research, they should learn to properly assess all given explanations.

So a term such as "revisionist position" or "revisionist history" is not only more polite, but also more accurate.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but when I hear "revisionist history" I imagine people fabricating new histories rather than just reinterpreting old ones, like how Big Brother invented the helicopter.